# binary search divide by 4

Tags: java, binary-search

Binary search divide array in 2 parts. But what if I want to divide the array in 4 parts ? 
Here is my approach

while (low <= h){
            quartal = (low + high) / 4;

```
        if (array[quartal] == x) return quartal;
        if (array[2*quartal] == x) return 2*quartal;
        if (array[3*quartal] == x) return 3*quartal;
        if (array[4*quartal] == x) return 4*quartal;

        if (array[quartal] > x) high = quartal-1;
        if (array[quartal] < x && array[2*quartal] > x){
            low = quartal + 1;
            high = 2*quartal-1;
        }
        if (array[2*quartal] < x && array[3*quartal] > x){
            low = quartal + 1;
            high = 2*quartal -1;
        }
        if (array[3*quartal] < x && array[4*quartal] > x){
            low = 2*quartal + 1;
            high = 3*quartal -1;
        }
        if (array[4*quartal] < x){
            low = 3*quartal + 1;

        }
```

that work but not for all values.
can someone tell me what wrong with my approach?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Binary search uses 2 parts because it is the most efficient way.

Comment: Show a case where that doesn't work

Comment: @dan1st. Technically not always

Comment: The limit of this approach is to brute-force check every element of the array: a linear search. For very small arrays, that may actually be faster since there is less bookkeeping involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what CodingTil has said.

You will have to do the following when doing your checks. Try to think of what would happen with edge cases like a length of 103 or just an array of [0,1]. In your code if we had an array length of 103, we would divide by 4 and get quartels of length 25.75. This can be problematic if we floor the quartel at the start as you'll miss out on values at index 101 and above. You'll have to adjust your other if statements in a similar manner.

```
    if (array[floor(quartal)] == x) return floor(quartal);
    if (array[floor(2*quartal)] == x) return floor(2*quartal);
    if (array[floor(3*quartal)] == x) return floor(3*quartal);
    if (array[high] == x) return high; // should be a whole number so no need to round
```

Your seventh if statement has an error (your eighth if statement will also have to be adjusted), it should read as follows. And I believe you'll be able to get rid of the ninth if statement altogether.

```
if (array[floor(2*quartal)] < x && array[floor(3*quartal)] > x){
    low = floor(2*quartal) + 1;
    high = floor(3*quartal) -1;
}

// high remains unchanged, as we are in the highest quartal
if (array[floor(3*quartal)] < x && array[floor(4*quartal)] > x){
    low = floor(3*quartal) + 1;
}
```

Comment: I totally agree!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

- Is your array sorted? Binary search only works on sorted arrays.
- In the last if-statement, you check if `array[4*quartal] < x`. Note that this can lead to errors, as `quartal` is an integer, and therefore `4*quartal` will not be equal to `(low + high)` but rather `4*floor((low+high)/4)`. Therefore, you may be dividing into 5 segments instead of 5 depending on if `(low+heigh)` is multiple of 4.

Because `4*quartal` should be the end of the segment in your array which you are searching in, I would suggest replacing `4*quartal` by `(low+high)`.

I hope this does help.